# Functional form

Tags: functions

Is there an analytic form of a function that satisfies the following:

$$\begin{align*}
f:\mathbb N &\to \mathbb N\\
1&\mapsto 1\\
2&\mapsto 2\\
3&\mapsto 2\\
4&\mapsto 3\\
5&\mapsto 3\\
6&\mapsto 3\\
7&\mapsto 4\\
&\vdots
\end{align*}$$

Comment: If you have the $n$th triangular number $T_n$ that is the smallest triangular number equal to or larger than $m$, note that $f(m)=n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $f(n)=4$ for $7 \le n \le 10$ (so there are $4 \ \ 4$'s and so on) you are finding the minimum $m$ such that $\frac 12 m(m+1) \ge n$, which is a [triangular number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).  To get an explicit formula, we can invert $\frac 12 m(m+1) = n$ by saying $ m^2+m-2n=0, m=\frac 12(-1+\sqrt{1+8n})$ and rounding up:  $$m=\left\lceil\frac 12\bigg(-1+\sqrt{1+8n}\bigg)\right\rceil$$